# How to stop popup from opening when I click on l.divicon custom html containing a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, esri-leaflet, esri-oss

I am using the esrileaflet library to render markers on a map having icon `l.divicon` which has a button in custom HTML.

I have bound an event to the button click which is called but also marker popup is opened which I don't want.

As `l.divicon` contains a button inside its custom HTML and its part of a marker, every time I click on the button it shows an alert and also opens the marker popup. How can I stop the marker popup?

```js
let markerIcon = L.divIcon({
  iconSize: L.point(32, 32),
  iconAnchor: [5, 5],
  html: '<div><img src= "url here"><button id="MyBtn"></button></div>'
});
marker.setIcon(markerIcon);

$("#MyBtn").on('click', function(e) {
  alert("Hi there");
});
```

Comment: A guess, but try adding `e.stopPropagation()` inside the `click` handler to stop the event bubbling up the DOM

Comment: Also try `e.preventDefault()`.

Comment: It worked thank you @RoryMcCrossan, share your answer and i will mark it as accepted.

Comment: Glad it helped. I added the answer for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like when the click event reaches the marker the popup appears. In which case, add `e.stopPropagation()` inside the `click` handler to stop the event bubbling up from `#MyBtn` to the marker.

```
$("#MyBtn").on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  alert("Hi there");
});
```